# How to fail war deployment if dependent war fails in wildfly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-9

I have 2 war files as below

1<sup>st</sup> is for DB jndi registration (jndi-reg.war).

2<sup>nd</sup> war (actual application)

This war deployment depends on **jndi-reg.war**, so for this I have added jboss-all.xml under /WEB-INF/ of second war,

**jboss-all.xml** as below

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
  <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
     <dependency name="jndir-reg.war" />
  </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

The problem is that I want to fail my application war if **jndi-reg.war fails** (like in case db credential is invalid)

But with above file war, under **standalone/deployment/apple.war.deployed** show war is deployed but not able to access it, So What things I should do to fail the application war in case if **jndi-reg.war** fails.

Comment: You could just make an EAR with the two WAR files in it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I have around 8 war files, And I don't think that make sense to change it to EAR.